# How to move object along SVG path on scroll and speed up specific sections

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I have a project in which I have a long SVG path. The SVG path is centered on the page and has a stroke "none" so that it is invisible. Then I have an image of a rocket. The idea is that this rocket should follow the path on scroll. Meaning for each pixel scrolled, it moves one pixel into the direction of the line.

This so far works great. I got the idea for my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188841/svg-animation-object-along-a-path-on-a-scroll) stackoverflow question.

My problem now is the specific path I created for this. The path has sections in which the path turns sideways or even up (for a looping). The rocket should still follow in these sections, which it does as you can see on the live example [here](https://vibrant-kirch-286ffc.netlify.app/test). But when moving through the looping the rocket leaves the view, because it is still moving at the same speed like the scrolling, but just away from the users scroll direction.

Now I would like to speed up the rocket when it is moving upwards through the looping so it doesn't leave out of view. Let's look at my code.

The Project is made in sveltekit, but that is not important right now because for my problem only the JS should be relevant. So for that matter here is the HTML:

```html
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; left:0; z-index:1000; pointer-events: none;" id="route">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 966 4692" id="svgRoute">
            <path id="path" d="M652 0V239.5V317.5C538.333 325.5 312.9 402.4 320.5 646C328.1 889.6 474.667 970.5 547 980.5C573.667 983 632 988.7 652 991.5C677 995 806 993 798 1118.5C791.6 1218.9 628 1275.67 547 1291.5C372.5 1294.67 30.1999 1323.2 56.9999 1412C90.4999 1523 171.5 1565.5 293.5 1607C415.5 1648.5 707 1657 786.5 1931C850.1 2150.2 436.667 2111 222 2064C64.5001 2047.5 -163.9 2094.8 182.5 2416C528.9 2737.2 800.5 2670.5 893 2597C984.5 2452 1061.5 2189 637.5 2297C213.5 2405 390.167 2773.67 531.5 2944.5C665.833 3062 924 3334.1 882 3482.5C829.5 3668 442 3885.5 420 3990C398 4094.5 764.5 4537 774 4691" stroke-width="5"  stroke="red" fill="none"/>
            <image id="c" x="-20" y="-70" width="40" height="70" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF4AAACqCAYAAAAk0fhhAAAFP0lEQVR4nO2dzWtcZRSH36tjGKdNOkOSFpqk+RAtqVGEtGahWLQQF0JMKBhQqKjVnVu7dK3gqiC4qGDAhQtpCC4kEOgsKooWQWuDYD9i81EH25RGrUlTx3/gnIvvzXWeKfk9y9+de8+dh7M4vPcrqdfrodlIkiTPk0qskP7f96HVtzESDyHxEBIPIfEQEg+RkGOVNzaOjR/LrcbM9JRb3tvQCCfqeAiJh5B4CImHkHiIQiOKxE4vn53+JLfakxN2PjM95Y4uSZL87wtr6ngIiYeQeAiJh5B4iFzXavKaXqpnvndrPLKv1cx79naa+WZxl5lPTrzq1ohd38niUB0PIfEQEg8h8RASDyHxENHjZNpdXnmNjW++9pZb/4Xxl8z8nbft1TBvzCwUS26NFyeOm3meY6Y6HkLiISQeQuIhJB4i10t/vV3tZp5levFY/u2Gmb9/8rSZe9NO/0CvW8P7H3mijoeQeAiJh5B4CImHaMgNTR4rK9fMfOixx6OP5U07zYo6HkLiISQeQuIhJB4CnWo8zv/4g7tt38PxE08zoo6HkHgIiYeQeAiJh5B4iIaMk+X2DjP/4suZ6GN598ffvLZs5qWW5uyt5jyrbYDEQ0g8hMRDSDxEQ6aa7p4uM+/YvcfMdxY23WO1ljbMvFqzb7su3vnHzO3KjUMdDyHxEBIPIfEQEg+BXvq7urBg5qWif1qd5fvN/OLyX2Y+tKsl/sQagDoeQuIhJB5C4iEkHiLXqWZ17U6ehzO5e/ummb/7rH1laj0pmvmvi7+7NRrxP9TxEBIPIfEQEg8h8RASD+GOk1m+t7ejtbK1s9kCV2prZj7QZ5/TqQ/tdx+EEMJPv9Riy5uuvNehh6COx5B4CImHkHgIiYeIXiTr6Xva3bZnb/+WTua/0NkR9/akv9ftG6CycGTUfq/m3Kz7PkoXdTyExENIPITEQ0g8RMFbkxl+cszcoVa7t96ElCdjky9H/X5u1v+snToeQuIhJB5C4iEkHiJ6raa1Yj9Ith3o7rK/N5IFdTyExENIPITEQ0g8hMRDoE/9tZXtm42KD6Ts05ayMScOHhox86WV67nVUMdDSDyExENIPITEQ7hTTblcNvNHB/zXiJ+tnonKb7Vwt3W3baxG7/PUc8/nVl8dDyHxEBIPIfEQEg8RvVazdMn/cEr17Ndm3ldfMvPjz9hvf2wZtCeqEEJ4sP8hM799+aKZb8zb7z746Cv/XQa3KvvNfMfUSXefWNTxEBIPIfEQEg8h8RDuI9/BeUw8C68fHDTzU684O4ymPMR2YMDOL1yy89nLZvzGp36Jj7+b9zdGcGT0mB6pbzYkHkLiISQeQuIhJB7CXSRLG4U80p5yi2F1wf6gSgghVA7E7ZPnxcX2nkOmkycG7XE5DXU8hMRDSDyExENIPEShXrcHkZRXJqKsXbAv5TWC61e/NfM5J09DHQ8h8RASDyHxEBIP4a7VeNNOGt4kdONP+zNxIdyNrrG54N+IFIN/TvFkcaWOh5B4CImHkHgIiYdAH6n/5vPdZj5y1P7AbgghrO7vNfPKz/Y+Xo0Q8ns8PgvqeAiJh5B4CImHkHgIiYdIsizwuAfzLxeaRQ53D5s/fq9vp1tj5Kj9OThvbDxx5Q8zry6ec2uMDw6Zf2R6/rz5ey2S3UNIPITEQ0g8hMRDNGSRzJ8SzpnjwIlgTzshhBA+KDkb4qaXw93DKXdsrfubckIdDyHxEBIPIfEQEg+R61qNW8RZw/HWaqqL9rSThfTpxcabhPJ0pY6HkHgIiYeQeAiJh5B4iH8BrZ8Mhx0ulsYAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
        </svg>  
    </div>
```

The div is id "route" and will be called as such multiple times throughout the JS. The `<path>` here is the line stretching through the whole page. The `<image>` is the rocket which I placed directly inside the SVG. The only relevant css is inside the style tag for the div.

Now for the JavaScript/jQuery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
        positionCar();          
    });

    // init the line car position
    positionCar();

    function positionCar() {
        var  scrollY = jQuery('#route').scrollTop() || window.pageYOffset;
        var  maxScrollY = jQuery('#route').prop('scrollHeight');
        var  path = document.getElementById("path");
        // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
        var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
        var  dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
        var  pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
        // Calculate position a little ahead of the car (or behind if we are at the end), so we can calculate car angle
        var angle = calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos)

        if (angle < 0) {
            var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
            var  dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
            var  pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
            var angle = calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos)
        }

        // Position the car at "pos" totated by "angle" (if angle is upwards position further for more speed)
        var  car = document.getElementById("c");
        car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (pos.x) + "," + (pos.y) + ") rotate(" + (rad2deg(angle) + 90) + ")");
    }

    function calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos) {
        if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
            var  posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
            return Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);

        } else {
            var  posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
            return Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
        }
    }

    function rad2deg(rad) {
        return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
    }

});
```

So jQuery checks if document ready and binds a scroll handler which then calls the positionCar() function everytime a scroll happens to place the rocket accordingly. The function basically calculates the position off the car on the path line by scroll position and path length. Then it uses the calculateAngle function to check for the required angle ahead of the path.

The angle is used so the rocket follows the path an turns in the direction of the path. Then the rocket (here called car) is positioned at that position in that specific angle.

The if condition inside the positionCar() function for now does nothing different. It checks if the angle is below zero indicating the path going upwards (for example the looping). My idea now is to implement more speed inside this condition because it tells when the rocket is moving back up instead of down.

How would I accomplish this. I tried playing with the calculations but it just resulted in jumping around. By changing the dist variable I managed to get the rocket faster during upwards movement. This just resulted in the rocket jumping back as soon as the path moves back down. How would I need t implement faster rocket speed only during the upwards movement?

For playing around with it I created a REPL with the full code here: https://svelte.dev/repl/d2e449585ac14ec8aef1fd310fb14548?version=3.46.4

Comment: Propositions for improving the question: 1. simplify example as much as possible, 2. include code directly in question, 3. adding a link to a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.46.4) is kind of a bonus, but often helpful

Comment: @Corrl thanks for the suggestions. I did not add code by design because it is so big (especially with svg definitions). I added a REPL, I think this showcases the code and it's functionality better than adding the code in here

Comment: Thanks to the REPL I now understand the problem :-) I still suggest that you simplify the example. Is the rotation/angle relevant for example? I spontaneously assume that not. (I guess it might be necessary to change how the length of the path and scroll are related...) If you reduce the code everything gets clearer and it's much easier to help. Even though the REPL is great, it might be deleted anytime, so including the code in the question is reasonable (and will prevent getting the one or other downvote... ;))

Comment: @Corrl The rotation just defines in which direction the rocket should be facing. I just thought that I could use it to determine if the line is moving upwards or not, because I want the rocket to be faster when moving upwards. I added the code here and a more in depth explanation

Comment: Yeah, I might be wrong and the rotation can help to handle this... thanks for the edit!