# CSS Animation move icon on page scroll to a path

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, css-animations

I want to create a CSS animation where an arrow moves along an SVG snake path while scrolling, and changes icon on every new section.

[Here is my page design for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k63k.png).

I looked at a few examples:

1. [codepen.io/yesvin/pen/XymwvX](https://codepen.io/yesvin/pen/XymwvX)
2. [codepen.io/gkando/pen/LYEvjOv](https://codepen.io/gkando/pen/LYEvjOv)

But I'm unable to recreate the intended behavior with my page design.

Here is my code so far:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let l = Path_440.getTotalLength();
  let dasharray = l;
  let dashoffset = l;
  e = document.documentElement;
  theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", l);
  theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", l);
  dashoffset = l - window.scrollY * l / (e.scrollHeight - e.clientHeight);
  //console.log('window.scrollY', window.scrollY, 'scrollTop', e.scrollTop, 'scrollHeight', e.scrollHeight, 'clientHeight', e.clientHeight, 'dash-offset', dashoffset);
  theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", dashoffset);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="246" height="2990" viewBox="0 0 246 2990" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                <path id="Path_440" d="M210.001 1.5C210.001 1.5 41.0015 324.5 6.50082 617.5C-27.004 902.042 182.501 1032.5 240.001 1313C275.095 1484.2 29.8527 1661 41.0008 1914.5C50.4751 2129.94 230.431 2237.5 235.001 2431.5C240.42 2661.59 41.0008 2988 41.0008 2988" stroke="#F39029" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="20 10"/>
                </defs>
                <use xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="1"/>
                <use id="theFill" xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
            </svg>
```

Comment: Are the codepen examples your own code, or just examples you got from somewhere else?

Comment: example somewhere else...

Comment: You attached the path as a PNG file. Could you provide some code or detail about what you have so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Andria i have added my progress so far

Comment: Does it have to be a CSS animation, or can it be something done on HTML Canvas?

Comment: @scribe I don't think OP meant that it has to be only CSS, but HTML Canvas might be too far off given we're animating and transforming SVG along an SVG path on scroll and nothing more complicated.

Comment: I was thinking, the path really just looks like a sin wave, why not just plot it on an html canvas and change it on scroll event?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the technique used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194605/1168892 might solve this problem here as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modern strategy is to use [CSS motion paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_motion_path) (a.k.a [`offset-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path) and [`path()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/path) in CSS). By calculating the `scrollProgress` of the SVG path, you can use that to calculate the [`offset-distance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-distance) for your icon as a percentage. Just make sure the icon is positioned absolutely at your SVG's `(0,0)`.

In the simple case that the SVG path spans the whole page, `scrollProgress` is just `window.scrollY / (docElt.scrollHeight - docElt.clientHeight)`. However, if the SVG path does not span the whole scroll container, then you need to use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to calculate the `scrollProgress` and clamp it between 0 and 1. The code demo below covers this more complex case.

To fill the path in as the user scrolls, combine the [`getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) method of path elements with `scrollProgress` to compute how far the user is along the path in pixels (`drawLength`) and how much they have left in pixels (`rest`). Then, you can use a common trick with [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) which is to set it to `${drawLength}px ${rest}px`.

Finally, you can also use `scrollProgress` to determine which icon to display with CSS [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). Use [`offset-rotate: 0rad;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-rotate) to prevent the icon from rotating in the direction of the path.

```js
pathIcon.style.offsetPath = `path('${Path_440.getAttribute("d")}')`;
const pathLength = Path_440.getTotalLength();

function clamp(min, val, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(min, val), max);
}

function updatePath() {
  const docElt = document.documentElement;
  const pathBox = theFill.getBoundingClientRect();

  // calculates scroll progress based on viewport progress
  const scrollProgress =
    clamp(0, -pathBox.y / (pathBox.height - docElt.clientHeight), 1);

  pathIcon.style.offsetDistance = `${scrollProgress * 100}%`;

  // These lines fill in the dashes as you scroll down.
  const drawLength = pathLength * scrollProgress;
  const rest = pathLength - drawLength;
  theFill.style.strokeDasharray = `${drawLength}px ${rest}px`;

  // You can update the icon/SVG here using your own logic.
  // For the example, I'm changing the CSS background-image.
  pathIcon.style.backgroundImage = `url(${getIconSrc(scrollProgress)})`;
}

function getIconSrc(scrollPercent) {
  if (scrollPercent < 0.2) {
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/FF0000?text=red';
  } else if (scrollPercent < 0.4) {
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/FFA500?text=orange';
  } else if (scrollPercent < 0.6) {
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/FFFF00?text=yellow';
  } else if (scrollPercent < 0.8) {
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/00FF00?text=green';
  } else if (scrollPercent < 1) {
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/0000FF?text=blue';
  } else if (scrollPercent === 1) {
    // A scrollPercent of 1 indicates that we have reached the end of the path.
    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/25x25/A020F0?text=purple';
  }
}

updatePath();
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => updatePath());
```

```css
#pathIcon {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-size: 25px;
  offset-rotate: 0rad;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 175px;"></div>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <svg width="246" height="2990" viewBox="0 0 246 2990" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <path id="Path_440"
                d="M210.001 1.5C210.001 1.5 41.0015 324.5 6.50082 617.5C-27.004 902.042 182.501 1032.5 240.001 1313C275.095 1484.2 29.8527 1661 41.0008 1914.5C50.4751 2129.94 230.431 2237.5 235.001 2431.5C240.42 2661.59 41.0008 2988 41.0008 2988"
                stroke-width="4" stroke="#F39029" />
        </defs>
        <use href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="20 10" />
        <use id="theFill" href="#Path_440" />
    </svg>
  <div id="pathIcon"></div>
</div>
```

---

***Hopefully, in the near future,*** we will get [scroll-driven animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/scroll-animations-1/) and even better support for CSS motion paths in browsers, which will make animating an element along a path significantly simpler with CSS alone.
For instance, if you are on Chrome Canary 115+ with the `experimental-web-platform-features` flag enabled, the following CSS works just as well if not better. No JS needed:

```css
#arrow {
  offset-path: url(#Path_440);
  offset-anchor: left;
  animation: offsetDistance linear;
  animation-timeline: scroll();
}

@keyframes offsetDistance {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="246" height="2990" viewBox="0 0 246 2990" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <path id="Path_440"
            d="M210.001 1.5C210.001 1.5 41.0015 324.5 6.50082 617.5C-27.004 902.042 182.501 1032.5 240.001 1313C275.095 1484.2 29.8527 1661 41.0008 1914.5C50.4751 2129.94 230.431 2237.5 235.001 2431.5C240.42 2661.59 41.0008 2988 41.0008 2988"
            stroke-width="4" stroke="#F39029" />
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="20 10" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" id="arrow" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M21.883 12l-7.527 6.235.644.765 9-7.521-9-7.479-.645.764 7.529 6.236h-21.884v1h21.883z" />
</svg>
```

[Learn more about how to use scroll-driven animations.](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/scroll-driven-animations/)

Comment: this is almost there.. just couple of more changes 1.) it is not filling up the dash. i want to fill up the dashes on scroll and 2.) i need to change pointers after some scroll for eg. right now it is arrow then maybe after scroll and reach to a point change it to different different n then again after scroll change to different...

Comment: Your question didn't ask to fill up the dashes, but I included that code anyways, just commented out; I will uncomment it. But as shown, you can update the icon at predetermined scroll intervals. I simply change the fill color, but you can replace the code to change it to different SVG elements or images. You should be able to figure that part out.

Comment: I would need assistance to change arrow.style.fill does I have to go for arrow.style.image and provide png or svg path?

Comment: if i have reduced the path height n width to 250 by 1504px this code stopped working

Comment: i guess it is because my path start from the middle of the page instead of top.. which is causing this to be half filled from start

Comment: I don't entirely understand your issue, but if your path is located somewhere other than the top-left corner of the page, simply wrap the path and icon in a `position: relative` parent element. This will reset the `inset` coordinate system to be relative to that common parent.

Comment: i have added the original design in the post. if you can see path starts from the middle of page or after few sections. so, on initial load it is coming as half filled n arrow also starts from that location only.

Comment: @KunalVijan I updated the code to support your more complex case of the path not spanning the entire scroll container. It requires calculating the `scrollPercent` a little differently, but the overall strategy remains the same.

Comment: sorry for asking this again but how do I change arrow to some other icon? do i have to update arrow.style.fill to something like arrow.style.image ?

Comment: @KunalVijan I think it's best to modify the element's [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) via `arrow.style.backgroundImage` = [`'url(...)'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) in JS. You may also need to use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to set the image size.

Comment: I tried to do the same but no luck.. else if (scrollPercent < 0.4) {
    arrow.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/avatar.png)";
  } if possible will you able to update the code n show me

Comment: @KunalVijan I updated the code to use `backgroundImage`, as well as simplified it to use CSS motion paths.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't exactly CSS Animation but produces the similar sort of effect. If you are open to something like this, this could be further polished.

I am just using the HTML Canvas to plot a Sin curve. Now, you do have to know some high school level trigonometry...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Path</title>
    <style>
      body,
      html,
      canvas {
        height: 99.6%;
        width: 99.6%;
      }
      canvas {
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the `canvas.js` has,

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
let delta = 100;
let n = 100;
addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  let c = 150;
  for (let i = n; i <= n; i++) {
    let x = (i * c * 2 * Math.PI) / (300*delta);
    let y = -c * Math.sin(x / c) + 600;
    ctx.fillRect(y, x, 3, 3);
  }
  n += delta;
});
```

And this is how it looks,

[image]

Comment: trigonometry was/is never my favorite

Comment: I don't like dentists either but they do make things easier ;-)